# Ubuntu 14.10 lower screen resolution and unable to use desktop

Tags: nvidia, updates, login, 14.10, ubuntu-drivers

System is Ubuntu 14.10 desktop 64-bit with Unity.

After reboot resolution changed to some lower one and I have black frame around the picture which is centered.

When I type password on login screen and hit enter i get my wallpaper and mouse pointer but no icons, no side panel. Still can see "Ubuntu 14.10" string in down left corner. I can move mouse around.

I can use terminals under `Ctrl+Alt+F1 - F6` and console via ssh. Older Ubuntu installation on other partition works fine so it is system related.

This PC is running almost 24/7 and I can't figure out what caused the issue.

I did `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm` but problem remains.

After more searching I removed `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` from home directory.
Also did `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session` but I'm still having this issue.

I'm using Nvidia GeForce 210 and NVIDIA binary driver from Additional Drivers (nvidia-331-updates).

Thanks.

Comment: Try to change the resolution with `xrandr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Then enable Unity Plugin in CompizConfig Settings Manager (must be installed of course).

========

Managed to bring back desktop.

Followed tips from here (for nvidia users) with little modification:

http://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo reboot
```

That gave me desktop with normal resolution, desktop icons but without top menu bar, no Launcher, no Dash. Programs could be started with command line.

Next I followed tips from here: 
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

`compizconfig-settings-manager` was installed so in terminal I typed `ccsm`.

After enabling Unity plugin things get back to normal but now I'm using nouveau graphics driver.

I don't know for sure but it looks like nvidia drivers issue. I followed first tips from first link (meaning without purging nvidia packages) and it didn't work.

**Edit 1:** Situation repeated on another Ubuntu PC with Nvidia GPU. During regular update problem with **`nvidia-331-updates`** was detected and reported. Then worked fine but symptoms described in first message appeared after reboot.

**Fix:** `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` then `reboot` and enable Unity plugin in CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Installing nvidia-331 (without "-updates") from Additional Drivers after that works fine.